# Continuing for loop only when image loads

Tags: javascript, image, object, canvas, onload

```
function readXML(){
    var xmlDoc = loadXML();
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (i == 600){
            break;
        }
        var path = x[i].getElementsByTagName("path")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var title = x[i].getAttribute("class");
        this.imageArray.push(new InfoImage(path,title));
        while(this.imageArray[i].isImageLoaded() == false); //something like this
        console.log(this.imageArray[i].getMaxPixels());

    }
}

function InfoImage(path,title){
    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = undefined;
    this.maxPixels = undefined;
    this.imageLoaded = false;

    this.init = function(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var img_Color = new Image_Processing_Color(canvas);
        var img = new Image();
        var info_image = this;
        img.onload = function () {
            img_Color.init(img);
            info_image.color = img_Color.getDominantColor();
            info_image.maxPixels = img_Color.getDominantColorPixels();
            info_image.imageLoaded = true;
        };
        img.src = path;
    };

    this.isImageLoaded = function(){
        return this.imageLoaded;
    }

    this.getPath = function(){
        return this.path;
    };

    this.getTitle = function(){
        return this.title;
    };

    this.getColor = function(){
        return this.color;
    };

    this.getMaxPixels = function(){
        return this.maxPixels;
    };

    this.init();
}
```

I want my `for` loop to only continue to the next iteration when img.onLoad completes. The `while` i'm using blocks the code and doesn't let img.onLoad complete. Is there a way to do this? Without changing the code structure.

Comment: Process the next image only when onload has been fired, don't use a loop. Make `InfoImage` take a callback which it execute when the onload function fire. Use it to execute a function which will check the next index in the array, if it is present it can add it if not it could call another function or run some other code pass that point. So start by adding index 0 if present and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the .complete property of an img:

var x = document.getElementById("myImg").complete;
the result can be true or false

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I believe your best option is to use [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) (if you want it to be serial, they have a function for it - series).

This function can perform a series of tasks for you and issue a callback on complete (in which you get informed of errors).